# r - Which() Match() function should I use to extract data based on colnames defined in another data.frame?

Tags: r, match, apply

I have a data frame of numbers for several thousand entities over time.  I have another data frame for the same time period with different column names over time:

```
> mfdf
#date Entity1 Entity2 Entity3 ... EntityN
#1988   1       13     16     ...  17
#1989   2       14     3      ...  11
#1990   6       15     8      ...  4
#...  ...      ...    ...     ...  6
#2018   4       1      8      ...  5
```

I would like to extract the corresponding entity numbers for the year, based on a data frame of column names:

```
> curationdf
#date  V1         V2
#1988 Entity64    Entity2
#1989 Entity1     Entity57
#1990 Entity1500  Entity70
#...
#2018 Entity23    Entity9
```

If this was done in excel, it would be an =IF(MATCH()) job, but I am unfamiliar with how to construct something similar in R programming.

Answer (score 0):

Not so short, but a solution with tidyr and dplyr:

```
gather(df,var,val,-year) %>% inner_join(curationdf,"year") %>% 
    filter((var==v1)|(var==v2)) %>%
    mutate(var=ifelse(var==v1,"v1","v2")) %>% spread(var,val)
```